# Power BI Calculated Items & Conditional Formatting (multiple measures)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting, measure

I would like to format some Calculated Items differently and have found a number of blogs/youtube videos which explain how to do this by creating a Measure and then applying this measure in Conditional Formatting. However, I am unable to get this to work as all proposed solutions assume that there is just one measure in the table, whereas I have multiple measures.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the measure I tried but didn't work...

ColourMeasure = 
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Time Intelligence'[Name] )
        IN { "Target 2023", "YTD" },
   SELECTEDMEASURE(),
    BLANK ()
)

Comment: I also tried creating the following calculated item, but the issue is that I cannot work out how to get it to read the Calculation Item name instead of the Measure Name. How do I do this?

VAR SelectedMeasureName = SELECTEDMEASURE()

RETURN
IF(
    SelectedMeasureName = "YTD",
    "YTD ", 
    SELECTEDMEASURE()
)